# How to get an Integer as User Input using Android buttons?

Tags: java, android, button, input, integer

I was checking out a few online tutorials for getting input from a user using a button such as [here][1], however it is not what I was after and wanted to know if any of you have come across a similar problem.

I want to get the user to get prompted to enter an `integer input` **ONLY** when the button is clicked and I dont want the `TextField` etc to show on the screen until the user has clicked the button. The user input has to be saved in the `int bias`.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Do you want to show only Integer values on the soft keyboard ?

Comment: @ShobhitPuri hi there, yes I only want the user to enter integer values for this case. Thank you

Comment: You can create a `PopupWindow` which will be shown when `grayScaleFilterButton` is clicked. The `PopupWindow` will contain an `EditText`. The value inputted by the user will be saved in variable `bias`.

Comment: @user2558882 I think thats what I am after! can you please put up an answer?!?!

Comment: if problem is solved don't forget to mark one of the answers as correct :)

Comment: `I think thats what I am after! can you please put up an answer?!?!` Posted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following code. The comments will guide you through it:

```
grayScaleFilterButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        // Show PopupWindow
        showPopup();

        // Everything after this will be handled in `doneInput(String)` method
    }
});
```

Declare the PopupWindow as a global variable:

```
// Right before onCreate(Bundle)
PopupWindow popupWindow;
```

Create a method `showPopup()` in your activity:

```
public void showPopup() {

    // Container layout to hold other components    
    LinearLayout llContainer = new LinearLayout(this);

    // Set its orientation to vertical to stack item
    llContainer.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);

    // Container layout to hold EditText and Button
    LinearLayout llContainerInline = new LinearLayout(this);

    // Set its orientation to horizontal to place components next to each other
    llContainerInline.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);

    // EditText to get input
    final EditText etInput = new EditText(this);

    // TextView to show an error message when the user does not provide input
    final TextView tvError = new TextView(this);

    // For when the user is done
    Button bDone = new Button(this);

// If tvError is showing, make it disappear 
    etInput.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            tvError.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
    });

    // This is what will show in etInput when the Popup is first created
    etInput.setHint("Please provide a number");

    // Input type allowed: Numbers
    etInput.setRawInputType(Configuration.KEYBOARD_12KEY);

    // Center text inside EditText
    etInput.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);

    // tvError should be invisible at first
    tvError.setVisibility(View.GONE);

    bDone.setText("Done");

    bDone.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            // If user didn't input anything, show tvError
            if (etInput.getText().toString().equals("")) {
                tvError.setText("Please enter a valid value");
                tvError.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                etInput.setText("");

            // else, call method `doneInput()` which we will define later
            } else {
                doneInput(etInput.getText().toString());
                popupWindow.dismiss();
            }
        }
    });

    // Define LayoutParams for tvError
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

    layoutParams.topMargin = 20;

    // Define LayoutParams for InlineContainer
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParamsForInlineContainer = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

    layoutParamsForInlineContainer.topMargin = 30;

    // Define LayoutParams for EditText
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParamsForInlineET = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

    // Set ET's weight to 1 // Take as much space horizontally as possible      
    layoutParamsForInlineET.weight = 1;

    // Define LayoutParams for Button
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParamsForInlineButton = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    // Set Button's weight to 0     
    layoutParamsForInlineButton.weight = 0;

    // Add etInput to inline container
    llContainerInline.addView(etInput, layoutParamsForInlineET);

    // Add button with layoutParams // Order is important
    llContainerInline.addView(bDone, layoutParamsForInlineButton);

    // Add tvError with layoutParams
    llContainer.addView(tvError, layoutParams);

    // Finally add the inline container to llContainer
    llContainer.addView(llContainerInline, layoutParamsForInlineContainer);

    // Set gravity
    llContainer.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);

    // Set any color to Container's background
    llContainer.setBackgroundColor(0x95000000);

    // Create PopupWindow
    popupWindow = new PopupWindow(llContainer, 
                                        ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                                             ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

    // Should be focusable
    popupWindow.setFocusable(true);

    // Show the popup window
    popupWindow.showAtLocation(llContainer, Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0);

}
```

At last, the `doneInput(String)` method:

```
public void doneInput(String input) {
    int bias = Integer.parseInt(input);

    // Work with it // For example, show a Toast
    Toast.makeText(this, "Number input by user was: " + bias, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    // Do anything else with input!
}
```

Note: No `xml` files are required for this. Copy, follow the instructions, and paste to try it out. You can show this `PopupWindow` anywhere on screen, in any size, and in any color.

Comment: Hi, your solution works however, after entering the user input, theres not way to get out of the text area because there is no way to `OK` or `Cancel`. can you please add that

Comment: @User1204501 I am sure that I added a `Done` button in the PopupWindow. Is it getting hidden behind the soft keyboard?

Comment: I would think could be a possibility, would you have any ideas on how to fix it?

Comment: @User1204501 Move this line ==> `llContainer.addView(bDone, layoutParams);` above `llContainer.addView(etInput);`. At least now, you'll be able to see and click the button. Later on, you can try moving the Button to some place better in the layout.

Comment: Cool, thanks for that, Ill select your answer as correct but if you find out how to align the done button then just update the answer. Thanks so much

Comment: @User1204501 You are welcome! I'll update the answer soon and leave you a comment.

Comment: Thank you for putting up with me haha!

Comment: @User1204501 Hi, took me while to get to this. Been busy. Now the EditText and Button show in line. The only changes required were in `showPopup()` method. So, copy the updated code above for `showPopup()` and give it a try. Let me know how it goes!

Answer (score 2):

Whatever is the `textField` that you are talking about, you can set input type like:

```
textFieldName.setRawInputType(Configuration.KEYBOARD_12KEY);
```

You can directly set it in the XML like:

```
android:inputType="number"
```

Also, even when you create the TextField, you can set the visibility to Invisible using :

```
textFieldName.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
```

Then when user clicks the button you can set it to Visible using:

```
textFieldName.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
```

You can change the visibility on Button click as you have mentioned in the question.

Comment: Hi, I havent created the Textfield because I dont want it to appear on the screen till the user clicks the button. And once the user clicks the button again the textfield has to disappear.

Comment: See updated answer. You can directly set it in TextView/EditText in XML. You can initially hide it as well and only show it only button click.

Comment: @User1204501: Then you should wrap the textfield in a AlertDialog

Comment: Hi can you upload full code because I am just a beginner and am not sure what you mean.

Comment: See the stuff regarding visibility. Please do mention which part is confusing you :)

Comment: So do I have to have `TextField` in the xml layout or am I hardcoding the whole `TextField`. What about have a pop up window to get the userinput so the textfield wouldnt affect the current layout

Comment: That sounds reasonable as well. I mean that wherever you create a text filed ( `TextView` or `EditText` ), you can specify that when keyboard pops up on clicking on it, what thing should appear in keyboard. That's what `setRawInput` and `inputType` does.

Comment: I am still confused =( would it be possible to upload ALL code and incoporating it using my code provided above. Then I would award you the best answer.

Comment: I think you need a dialogue to get the user input and upon clicking ok use the inputted int in your code. If it is so please see my answer.

Answer (score 2):

You can add this textfield in the layout and set its visibility `"gone"`

```
boolean isClicked  =  false;
String userInput = null;

Button grayScaleFilterButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.filter1_button);
    grayScaleFilterButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
        if(isClicked){
         isClicked = false;
              //Got the input and hide the textfield.
             userInput  = textField.getText().toString();
             textField.setVisibility(View.GONE);

        }else{
              //make the textfield visible and user can enter the input.
          isClicked = true;
              textField.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER);
          textField.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        //do something

        }


        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

to display on number in keyboard add this line `android:inputType="number"` to your EditText

```
 <EditText android:id="@+id/edittext"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:inputType="number"
   />
```

if you want to display edittext into dialog then use customdialog [Dialogs Example](http://androidsolution4u.blogspot.in/2012/10/android-dialogs-tutorial-for-begginer.html) and use `mDialog.show()` in button click listener.

here `mDialog` is object of `Dialog`

Comment: Don't think this is a complete answer: OP said `I want to get the user to get prompted to enter an integer input ONLY when the button is clicked and I dont want the TextField etc to show on the screen until the user has clicked the button`.

Answer (score 1):

on button click it shows an alterDialogue for user to input. once some value is inputted it shows it in the corresponding textview. Here is the whole code:

```
package com.example.testandroidapp;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    TextView input1;
    String value = "";
    int bias;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Button grayScaleFilterButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        input1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);

        grayScaleFilterButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {

                AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(v
                        .getContext());

                alert.setTitle("Title");
                alert.setMessage("Message");

                // Set an EditText view to get user input
                final EditText input = new EditText(MainActivity.this);
                alert.setView(input);

                alert.setPositiveButton("Ok",
                        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                                    int whichButton) {
                                value = input.getText().toString();

                                // Convert the inputted string into Integer
                                bias = Integer.parseInt(value);
                            }
                        });

                alert.setNegativeButton("Cancel",
                        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                                    int whichButton) {
                                // Canceled.
                            }
                        });

                alert.show();

            }
        });

        input1.setText(value);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

}
```

Comment: Hi this is great, however, what does the getContext() contain?

Comment: `final EditText input = new EditText(alert.getContext());` // the getContext gives an error and asks for a cast

Comment: You can replace v.getContext() with MainActivity.this and this is the Context.

Comment: Sorry about the late one but your code crashes for some reason. =(

Answer (score 1):

XML code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/edtInput"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:inputType="number"
            android:visibility="gone" />

        <Button 
            android:id="@+id/btnInput"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:text="Input"/>
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Activity code

```
public class MyInputActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

    private EditText edtInput;
    private Button btnInput;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.my);

        edtInput = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edtInput);
        btnInput = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnInput);

        btnInput.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View arg0) {
        if(edtInput.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE){
            edtInput.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            // write your more code here on gone
        }else{
            edtInput.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            // write your more code here on visible
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can set input type number by this line in xml: using this code user can click 0,1,..9 digits only from sofrtware keyboard:

```
       android:digits="1234567890" or  android:inputType="number"
```